# Are there any starting D&D 4e adventures being published?

Tags: dnd-4e

I'm trying to prepare for a low-prep-time starting game for D&D 4e.  The obvious solution would be to buy a prepackaged adventure for 4e for 1st level characters.  However, from what I can see, only one (H1, "Keep on the Shadowfell") was produced to prepare characters for the sequence (H1-H2-H3-P1-etc) and it's out of print.

That seems a bit weird to me, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something.  Is there a replacement starting adventure for this that would prepare characters correctly for the next adventure, H2?  Should I go with HS1...but then how would I get from there to H2 (There seems to be a large level gap)?  Is there another prepackaged option out there, possibly from another company?

Comment: Please see also: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11845/what-is-a-good-first-heroic-campaign-for-dd-4e-levels-1-5

Comment: @F.RandallFarmer Yep, I did...and I voted it up and favorited it before I posted this.  It was a close call about whether it was similar enough that I shouldn't post this one, but the other one didn't really answer my exact question, so I decided to ask.  However, it's a great resource that I'll be jumping back to...especially Raddu's answer regarding Chaos Scar!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a lot of 1st level adventures published through Dungeon magazine. Some of them are free to everyone and some of them require DDI access to download them.

H1 (Keep on the Shadowfell) is now [available for free](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/h1.pdf) on Wizards' website.

There is also HS1 ([Slaying Stone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786953888)) which is apparently a pretty good L1 adventure.

If you want one of the best introductions to 4e, the [Red box](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786956291)'s introductory adventures are really good (I'd ignore a lot of its character creation stuff and use more standard character creation). It also leads right into the [DM kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786956305) and [Monster Vault](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786956313) adventures quite well. I'd go this route if you meet any of the following criteria: Want monster tokens, are completely new to 4e, want to have adventures in print or want to have a couple of nice printed maps

However, if you don't need something in print, or don't want to buy something, I'd really suggest grabbing something out of Dungeon to run (I'm getting ready to start the Chaos Scar series with my group and it looks pretty good and runs from L1-L12). Make sure you pick something from one of the more recent issues so that it uses the most recent errata. Even if you have to get a month or two of DDI it will still save you money (vs buying books) and make your life easier when it comes to looking up rules and possibly creating characters.

Comment: Right on!  I added a link to the mentioned download.  Many thanks...I'll probably try to use this as an excuse to re-up my subscription.

Comment: @Beska thanks. I'm at work else I would have :).

Comment: I believe that Madness at Guardmore Abby continues on where the DM Kit and Monster Vault adventures finish off.